# PHP echo formatted JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, echo

How do I insert a formatted javascript to have newline in php?

I want my script to display this way but I can't seem to echo newlines.

The script is inserted into the html in one line.

```
<script>
  var a;
  var b;
</script>
```

It comes out this way:

```
<script> var a; var b; </script>
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: already tried it but still got a script inserted as one line. I tried using " and ' but it didn't work.

Comment: Really? http://codepad.org/TW2ycnPE

Comment: Why is this PHP related? Please post the php-related part of your code. How do you insert your code?

Answer (score 2):

If you want indention in html source you can use `\n`. For example-

```
echo "\n<script> \n\tvar a;\n\tvar b; \n</script>";
```

Or you can use, as already posted by Laukik

```
<?php
echo <<<HTML_ENTITIES
<script>
  var a;
  var b;
</script>
HTML_ENTITIES;
?>
```

Which will produce the source like-

```
<script>
  var a;
  var b;
</script>
```

Or if you want this in design than use `<pre></pre>` tag at start of your javascript code on the page where you want to show your code, than you will get same indention of html for particular script section.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<?php
echo <<<HTML_ENTITIES
<script>
  var a;
  var b;
</script>
HTML_ENTITIES;
?>
```

Comment: sorry. Just inserted your code and it inserted the code correctly. I'm using adsense and the <ins> part isn't formatted correctly how do I correct it.

Comment: <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxx">
     </ins>

Comment: what are you getting in output with your code now and what do you want in output?

Answer (score 0):

if you are printing from your script tag from php 
use 
      echo    \n
      var a; \n
        var b; \n
        ;

Answer (score 0):

You could jump in and out of php like this:

```
?>
<script>
  var <?php echo "a"; ?>;
  var <?php echo "b"; ?>;
</script>
<?php
```

Just substitute the "a" and "b" strings with the actual variables you want to output.

Comment: Opposed to a version where you echo it all out in one big string, e.g. <?php echo "<script>var a; var b;</script>";?> This has the extra benefit that your editor will know which part of your code is javascript and which is php, so that you can enjoy stuff like syntax highlighting and autocomplete.

Answer (score -1):

Use pre tag at start of your php page than you will get same indention of html for whole document including Script tag.